# Get Instance count and memory details from AWS EMR Cluster-id

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Hi I would like to get Instance count and Total available memory and Memory for each instance in the cluster.

When I submit `aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id 'cluster-id' --region us-east-1` then I get a json output, which has all the information, but is there any way to filter just below 3 details.

1. Instance count,
2. Instance memory and
3. Total memory in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS CLI has a `--query` parameter which can be used to specify the output fields desired.

See: [Controlling Command Output from the AWS CLI - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html)

Therefore, you could use:

```
aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id 'cluster-id' --query Cluster[]. InstanceGroups[].[InstanceType,RunningInstanceCount]
```

I couldn't see any output values listed for memory, but the above should get you started.